# delphi finalizalization code in a DLL

Tags: delphi, dll

I am moving some functions to a shared DLL (I want to have some called as a Windows hook).

The actual functions are currently in a `unit`, and it happens to have some `initialization` and some `finalization` code.

I was initially thinking on doing a direct transformation from a `unit` to a `library`. So I  moved the `initialization` code in between the main `begin` and `end.`. But then I realized I had no place to move the `finalization` code. I should create and register an special DLL entry point, instead.

My question is. Can I leave the `unit` with all the functions and the `initialization` and `finalization` codes and just create a `library` stub that `uses` the unit?  will the `finalization`it be called?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Code in the initialization sections of the units in the DLL will run when the DLL is first loaded in to the process. The finalization sections fire when the DLL is unloaded from the process.

Eugene is right that you can have more fine-grained control using DLLProc but this is usually only needed for per-thread resources, e.g. thread local storage.

I would point out that there are serious limitations on what can be done during [DLLMain](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682583.aspx) which is ultimately where these initialization/finalization sections originate when inside a library. The MSDN documentation basically says that you can do some things, but that there is no list of acceptable behaviour.  The closest it comes is to saying that you can call functions in kernel32.  Otherwise, all bets are off!

There are lots of articles on the web that describe the issue, but beyond the MSDN topic for DLLMain that I've linked above, I would recommend reading Microsoft's [Best Practices for Creating DLLs](http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/driver/kernel/DLL_bestprac.mspx).

The helpful advice that MSDN offers is that the library can mandate that its users call an initialization function before using the DLL. A corresponding finalization function would be called once you were finished with the DLL.  The use of comctl32.dll adopts this idiom, see [InitCommonControlsEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb775697(v=VS.85).aspx).

In my own code I prefer an alternative approach.  The initialization sections of all my units register initialization and finalization methods.  Then, on the first call to any exported function from my library, the initialization methods are run, in the order in which they were registered.  This is not a problem for me to implement because I am already controlling all entry/exit points to my library.

I realise this is more than you asked for, but you may find it helpful to avoid some rather hard to debug problems.

Comment: +1. In short, code in a finalization section *will* get called, but due to the OS loader lock, you might not want it to. Avoid possible deadlock: Export explicit initialization and finalization functions for the host process to call.

Comment: The Old New Thing explains why: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/01/27/63401.aspx

Comment: @Jeroen I was going to link to that article, but that's a bit of a curate's egg and the articles that Raymond links to appear to have been eaten by MS link rot. The best reference I have found is http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/driver/kernel/DLL_bestprac.mspx

Comment: great; thanks for digging up this better article. Wish I could do +1 twice.

Answer (score 4):

The initialization of a unit will be called if its a program and if its a library.

Same for the finalization.

So yes, you can leave the unit as it is and export the required functionality.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest that you implement a DLLMain and handle different situations (process attach, thread attach etc) by calling dedicated procedures/functions for each situation. Then you can call the needed procedures/functions from initialization and finalization, if you need to switch from DLL to unit. The reason is that you might need some fine-grain control when the DLL is attached/detached to/from the thread (which will happen when you set a system-wide hook).

Comment: You shouldn't, and The Old New Thing explains why: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/01/27/63401.aspx

Comment: @Jeroen this is all words. In fact, when implementing system-wide hooks (and I wrote a bunch of them) in many cases you need to use DLLMain and track thread attachment.  This is due to the nature of system-wide hooks.

Answer (score 0):

This happend to me as well.
I found out that I had a unit, that initialization section that create a thread or doing some stuff, when the dll is registered.

I have removed this initialization section, and it worked fine.

Since, the initialization is required for .exe application but not for dll application, 
there is a variable flag in the system utility, called ModuleIsLib
just do:

```
initialization

if not ModuleIsLib then
 begin
// initialization stuff for .exe file
 end;
```

This can be done also for finalization section as well.

hope it helped..!